# Trouble with SpringPad API

Tags: php, api, oauth

I'm trying to access date using the Springpad API.

If I use the following link:

```
http://springpadit.com/api/blocks/all?limit=1&text=HARRY+POTTER
```

I have no problem getting 2 recent results with the search term "J K Rowlings'.

I wrote the following code to do the same thing after authorizing my server:

```
$api_url = "http://springpadit.com/api/";
$query = $_GET['query'];
$param = array('limit'=>1, 'text'=>$query);
$temp = http_build_query($param,"","&");
$url = $api_url."blocks/all?".$temp;

session_start();

// In state=1 the next request should include an oauth_token.
// If it doesn't go back to 0
if(!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && $_SESSION['state']==1) $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
try {
  $oauth = new OAuth($conskey,$conssec,OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
  $oauth->enableDebug();
  if(!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
    $request_token_info = $oauth->getRequestToken($req_url);
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $request_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];
    $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
    header('Location: '.$authurl.'?oauth_token='.$request_token_info['oauth_token'].'&oauth_token_secret='.$_SESSION['secret']);
    exit;
  } else if($_SESSION['state']==1) {
    $oauth->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'],$_SESSION['secret']);
    $access_token_info = $oauth->getAccessToken($acc_url);
    $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
    $_SESSION['token'] = $access_token_info['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $access_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];
  } 
  $oauth->setToken($_SESSION['token'],$_SESSION['secret']);
  $oauth->fetch($url);
  $json = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse(),true);
  print_r($json['blocks']);
} catch(OAuthException $E) {
  print_r($E);
}
```

This should let you create the same query and retrieve the data by using the following link:

http://xrefpro.com/CRM/index.php?query=HARRY+POTTER

All I get is an empty array for my results.  What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: What does var_dump($oauth->getLastResponse()); give you?

Comment: @kyle-hudson it gives me 

string(15) "{ "blocks":[] }"

Comment: ok well that would suggest that nothing is been returned from springpadit.

Comment: I understand that.  I can get it to work with other parts of their API, but am having lots of problems whenever it comes to using their filters.  If you go directly to the [Link that is created](http://springpadit.com/api/blocks/all?limit=1&text=HARRY+POTTER), then it outputs the block.  I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong in my code to get the same output through the fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The springpad api call "/api/blocks/all" is a global search across all users public data. It does not require auth. There does seem to be a bug with the api that causes that search to not work if you are logged in. You can test this by logging out of springpad and hitting

```
http://springpadit.com/api/blocks/all
```

and then try it when logged in.

I imagine what is happening is it is trying to find a block with that text in your own account. I am an employee at springpadit.com, we will look into fixing that bug with global queries. For now though, don't bother with oauth for a global query.

If you want to search your own account, use oauth and query

```
http://springpadit.com/api/users/me/blocks?limit=1&text=Thor
```

The response won't have a "blocks" node, so just change the print to

```
print_r($json);
```